# Rails RABL helper send object from index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I have such index.rabl:

```
collection @exchangers, :root => "bank", :object_root => false

extends "exchanger_lists/show"
```

and such show.rabl:

```
object @exchanger
attributes :id, :name, :address, :location_id, :latitude, :longitude, :exchanger_type_id
node(:location_name) {|exchanger_list| exchanger_list.location.name }
node(:exchanger_type_name) {"normal" }
child currencies(@exchanger)  do
  attribute :value, :direction_of_exchange_id, :exchanger_list_id
end
```

my contoller is such:

```
  def index
    @exchangers = ExchangerList.all
  end
  def show
    @exchanger = ExchangerList.find(params[:id])
  end
```

When i open in browser my show action, all is ok, to my helper is sended @exchanger object, all ok. But! when i call index action i get:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

with data all is ok...

How to send when i use index rabl view to helper @exchanger object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh) 
Find in by-myself, will share:

all i must to write was:
root_object

```
object @exchanger
attributes :id, :name, :address, :location_id, :latitude, :longitude, :exchanger_type_id
node(:location_name) {|exchanger_list| exchanger_list.location.name }
node(:exchanger_type_name) {"normal" }
child currencies(root_object)  do
  attribute :value, :direction_of_exchange_id, :exchanger_list_id
end
```